# Wrap monaco Ranges in custom html tags

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

So I want to use monaco to show code and some inline based changes, for that reason I'd like to add span tags around the changed elements and make them clickable etc.

This is what happens when you create some Ranges and give them a class:

```
var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([], [
    { range: new monaco.Range(7,7,7,17), options: { inlineClassName: 'UPDATE' }},
    { range: new monaco.Range(7,1,7,24), options: { inlineClassName: 'INSERT' }}
]);
```

[image]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wedenigc/d2thbo0a/2/

As you can see, this splits up my spans, especially noticable when you hover over them. So instead of adding a class to all the subelements I want to add a opening tag at the start and a closing tag at the end of my range.
The difference in HTML would be:

```
<!-- previous code -->
<span><span class="mtk1 INSERT">Person</span><span class="mtk1 UPDATE INSERT">.prototype</span><span class="mtk1 INSERT">.getAge</span>

<!-- new html -->
<span><span class="mtk1 INSERT">Person<span class="mtk1 UPDATE">.prototype</span>.getAge</span>
```

```css
html, body, #container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.INSERT {
 border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: greenyellow;
    padding: 2px;
}

.UPDATE {
 border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 2px;
}

.UPDATE:hover {
    padding: 3px;
}

.INSERT:hover {
    padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<span><span class="mtk1 INSERT">Person</span><span class="mtk1 UPDATE INSERT">.prototype</span><span class="mtk1 INSERT">.getAge</span>

<span><span class="mtk1 INSERT">Person<span class="mtk1 UPDATE">.prototype</span>.getAge</span>
```

This behaviour can be fixed by using `className` instead of `inlineClassName` but then the hover stops working.

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wedenigc/d2thbo0a/3/